# Unix set path not working

Tags: unix, path

I installed a package `s2cmd` on my unix machine. It works fine when I run it from the folder it resides in, but it did not run from other locations so I set the PATH using the command `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bitnami/S3Tools/s3cmd-1.5.0-alpha1` there is a file `s3cmd` inside this folder which has to be executed.

The problem now is when I do a `which s3cmd`, I get the correct path as output but when I run it using, say `sudo s3cmd`, it says `command not found`. If I give the absolute path and try to run it, its runs from any location.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT :** I just noticed that there are 2 PATH variables with the same path. Is that causing the problem? If yes, how do I correct it?

```
$ set | grep PATH
PATH=/opt/bitnami/rvm/bin:/opt/bitnami/memcached/bin:/opt/bitnami/varnish/bin:/opt/bitnami/redis/bin:/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin:/opt/bitnami/mercurial/bin:/opt/bitnami/perl/bin:/opt/bitnami/git/bin:/opt/bitnami/nginx/sbin:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/app/Console:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/cakephp/app/Console:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/codeigniter/bin:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/symfony/bin:/opt/bitnami/frameworks/zendframework/app/Console:/opt/bitnami/sphinx/bin:/opt/bitnami/sqlite/bin:/opt/bitnami/apps/django/bin:/opt/bitnami/php/bin::/opt/bitnami/java/bin:/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin:/opt/bitnami/postgresql/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/subversion/bin:/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/bitnami/S3Tools/s3cmd-1.5.0-alpha1:/opt/bitnami/S3Tools/s3cmd-1.5.0-alpha1
_=PATH                                                                                                                                                                                 
    export PATH;                                                                                                                                                                       
            PATH="$2:$PATH"                                                                                                                                                            
            PATH="$PATH:$2"                                                                                                                                                            
        PATH="${rvm_user_path_prefix}:$PATH";                                                                                                                                          
    PATH="$(printf "%b" "$PATH"           | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: '!($0 in a){a[$0];print}')";                                                                                          
    PATH="${PATH/%:/}";                                                                                                                                                                
    export PATH;                                                                                                                                                                       
    if printf "%b" "${PATH//:/ }" | GREP_OPTIONS="" \grep -vF "${rvm_bin_path}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then                                                                                 
                PATH="$PATH:${rvm_bin_path}"                                                                                                                                           
                PATH="${rvm_bin_path}:$PATH"                                                                                                                                           
        printf "%b" "export PATH ; PATH=\"${rvm_ruby_gem_home}/bin:${rvm_ruby_global_gems_path}/bin:${rvm_ruby_home}/bin:${rvm_bin_path}:\$PATH\"\n" > "$file_name";                   
        for variable in rvm_env_string rvm_path rvm_ruby_string rvm_gemset_name RUBY_VERSION GEM_HOME GEM_PATH MY_RUBY_HOME IRBRC MAGLEV_HOME RBXOPT;                                  
    export PATH;                                                                                                                                                                       
            \awk '/PATH/' < "$actual_file";                                                                                                                                            
            rvm_error "Neither md5 nor md5sum were found in the PATH";                                                                                                                 
            rvm_error "Neither md5 nor md5sum were found in the PATH";                                                                                                                 
    export PATH;                                                                                                                                                                       
    PATH=":$PATH:";                                                                                                                                                                    
    PATH="${PATH//:$1:/:}";                                                                                                                                                            
    PATH="${PATH//::/:}";                                                                                                                                                              
    PATH="${PATH%:}";                                                                                                                                                                  
    PATH="${PATH#:}"                                                                                                                                                                   
    PATH="$(printf "%b" "$PATH"           | awk -v RS=: -v ORS=: "/${rvm_path//\//\/}/ {next} {print}")";                                                                              
    PATH="${PATH/%:/}";                                                                                                                                                                
    export PATH;                                                                                                                                                                       
    export GEM_HOME GEM_PATH MY_RUBY_HOME RUBY_VERSION IRBRC;                                                                                                                          
                rvm_error "Neither sha256sum nor shasum found in the PATH";                                                                                                            
                rvm_error "Neither sha256sum nor shasum found in the PATH";                                                                                                            
        export GEM_HOME GEM_PATH MY_RUBY_HOME RUBY_VERSION IRBRC;                                                                                                                      
        GEM_PATH="$rvm_ruby_gem_path";                                                                                                                                                 
        unset BUNDLE_PATH;                                                                                                                                                             
            GEM_PATH="$GEM_PATH:$MAGLEV_HOME/lib/maglev/gems/1.8/";                                                                                                                    
            new_path="$GEM_HOME/bin:$rvm_ruby_global_gems_path/bin:$MY_RUBY_HOME/bin:${rvm_bin_path}:$(__rvm_remove_rvm_from_path ;printf "%b" "$PATH")";                              
            new_path="$GEM_HOME/bin:$MY_RUBY_HOME/bin:${rvm_bin_path}:$(__rvm_remove_rvm_from_path ;printf "%b" "$PATH")";                                                             
        export PATH="$new_path";                                                                                                                                                       
    unset GEM_HOME GEM_PATH MY_RUBY_HOME RUBY_VERSION IRBRC;                                                                                                                           
    new_path="$(__rvm_remove_rvm_from_path ; printf "%b" "$PATH"):${rvm_bin_path}";                                                                                                    
    new_path="$PATH:${rvm_bin_path}";                                                                                                                                                  
    COMPREPLY=($( eval PATH="$PATH:/sbin" $cmd 2>/dev/null |         awk '/^[^ \t]/ { print $1 }' ));                                                                                  
    if [[ -z "${CDPATH:-}" || "$cur" == ?(.)?(.)/* ]]; then                                                                                                                            
    for i in ${CDPATH//:/'                                                                                                                                                             
    if [ "${INFOPATH: -1:1}" == ':' ]; then                                                                                                                                            
        infopath=${INFOPATH}${infopath};                                                                                                                                               
        if [ ${INFOPATH:+set} ]; then                                                                                                                                                  
            infopath=$INFOPATH;                                                                                                                                                        
    COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lsmod |         awk '{if (NR != 1) print $1}' )" -- "$1" ))                                                                        
    [ -z "$classpath" ] && classpath=$CLASSPATH;                                                                                                                                       
    local PATH="$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin";                                                                                                                                                
        manpath=$MANPATH;                                                                                                                                                              
    COMPREPLY=(${COMPREPLY[@]:-} $( compgen -W         "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lspci -n | awk '{print $3}')" -- "$cur" ))                                                               
    local PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin;                                                                                                                                  
    COMPREPLY=("${COMPREPLY[@]}" $( compgen -W         "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ifconfig -a |         sed -ne 's/.*addr:\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p'             -ne 's/.*inet[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p' )"         -- "$cur" ))
    COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W         "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" sysctl -N -a 2>/dev/null )" -- "$cur" ));                                                                                  
    COMPREPLY=(${COMPREPLY[@]:-} $( compgen -W         "$( PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lsusb | awk '{print $6}' )" -- "$cur" ))                                                                 
                        GEM_PATH="$rvm_ruby_gem_home:$rvm_ruby_gem_home${rvm_gemset_separator:-"@"}global";                                                                            
                        export rvm_ruby_gem_home GEM_HOME GEM_PATH;
```

Comment: When you invoke sudo, the PATH is not normally reset.  However it is possible to set an option which resets it.  Check if `env_reset` is set in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: you'll have to give us an example of '2 PATH variables with the same path' Edit your question to include the output of `set | grep PATH`. Good luck.

Comment: Note that `env_reset` may or may not reset `PATH`, depending on how `sudo` was compiled.

Comment: If you’re going to talk about shell builtin commands like `set`, you need to say what shell you’re using (e.g., `bash`, `csh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.)  It looks like you’re running a shell where the `set` command outputs all variables _and shell functions_ –– so you’re getting every line from every shell function that contains the string `PATH`, including some that set PATH.  This is a red herring.  If you distrust `echo "$PATH"`, try `env | grep "^PATH="`.

Comment: You say, “It works fine when I run it from the folder it resides in.”  Do you mean with `sudo`?  What happens if you run it without `sudo`?  … if you run it without `sudo` from another directory?  (If you get a permissions error, that confirms that you set PATH correctly; if you get a “not found” error, that suggests that you didn’t.)  Can you do `sudo sh`, `sudo bash`, `sudo -s`, or equivalent?  If so, do that and then repeat the other steps (`s3cmd`, `which s3cmd`, `echo "$PATH"`).  If your `PATH` variable has been replaced by a default, go back and try `sudo -E` to preserve the environment.